# How to configure Amazon SES SMTP in PHP Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-ses

I have integrated Amazon SES in PHP Laravel5 project but i have troubled to send email's because i am getting this error,

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 Authentication required"
```

Can anyone tell me how to configure Amazon SES..

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this? I can send through SwiftMailer by itself fine but when I try and use laravel mail with the env settings as SMTL /TLS (same as swiftmailer) I get the same error as you

Answer (score 21):

Ensure you have configured your environment variables:

like the following:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=AKIAJ3RS7BUIV7U2LCIQ
MAIL_PASSWORD=Av9/1W4ZfcinolyP+8PNvjyQk7owOxaIMUehg53/QhnH
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I just open a terminal and wrote the following commands:

`> Composer update`(optional)

`> php artisan queue:restart`

then it should work.

You have to write to support and ask for moving out of the amazon ses sand box

hope helps

Comment: Have tried the above solution but it didn't work , stil getting the same error.

Comment: I also ask for moving out of the amazon ses sand box, and it works http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: Do we need install aws-sdk?

Comment: you need to install "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0"

Comment: This method does not use `aws/aws-sdk-php` package because it uses direct `SMTP` protocol to connect to the AWS SES and send emails. In order to use the SES SDK API, which is the correct and *safe* way to send emails using users with corresponding permissions, we need to set the `MAIL_MAILER` to `ses` and apply `AWS_*` keys inside `.env` file.

Answer (score 5):

modify `config/mail.php` 's `driver` to `ses`, and check the information in `config/services.php`

```
'ses' => [
    'key' => 'your-ses-key',
    'secret' => 'your-ses-secret',
    'region' => 'ses-region',  // e.g. us-east-1
],
```

or add them to your `.env` file.

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this? I can send through SwiftMailer by itself fine but when I try and use laravel mail with the env settings as SMTL /TLS (same as swiftmailer) I get the same error as you

Answer (score 2):

I have added this in .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=YOURHOST
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_USERNAME 
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_Password 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls 
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Name" 
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="from@email.com"
```

for sending email I have used this.

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'view_name'], $data, function ($m) use ($email) {
    $m->from('support@email.com', 'name');
    $m->to($email, $email)->subject('email subject');
});
```

after changing this hit this "php artisan serve " command in terminal

Comment: Go to SES -> Email Addresses -> Verify New Email Address - then verify a new email address.  Then use MAIL_FROM_NAME="Name"  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="from@email.com" as shown in answer, that worked for me.