# How to use my servers SMTP details to send emails in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

Currently, I'm using sendgrid as email service in my Laravel applications. I just curious to know can I use my server's SMTP details to send emails, like in WordPress.

Comment: check config/mail.php

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I can add SMTP details. But is it working like that WordPress mail function?

Comment: I don't know how WP works, but you can absolutely send emails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858896/how-to-configure-amazon-ses-smtp-in-php-laravel-5 please check this link, you will get your answer